# Signing requests with Twitter API

Tags: c#, oauth, twitter

Here is a problem that is driving me crazy: the code below works perfectly for the first URL (lookup), but not for the second one (update status). I get an Incorrect signature error with my request...

```
url = string.Format("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.xml?screen_name={0}", myOAuth.UrlEncode("someuser"));
url = string.Format("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.xml?status={0}", myOAuth.UrlEncode("bla bla bla"));

string oAuthSignature = myOAuth.GenerateSignature(new Uri(url), consumerKey, consumerSecret, token, tokenSecret, httpMethod, timeStamp, nonce, signatureType, out normalizedUrl, out normalizedRequestParameters);
string encodedSign = myOAuth.UrlEncode(oAuthSignature);

// Rebuild query url with authorization
this.richTextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}?{1}&oauth_signature={2}", normalizedUrl, normalizedRequestParameters, encodedSign);
```

May it come from the fact that the first url is a GET method, and the second a POST method ?
I'm stuck here so I take any idea, and thank you for your help ;)

Comment: All you'll get is conjecture if you don't post the code for your `GenerateSignature` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a small piece of conjecture.

**Possible problem 1**.

The update api will only work if actually send it as a POST request (not only sign it as a POST request). When twitter recreates your signature to verify the signature you send, it checks which http method the request was sent with and uses that information to create a signature base string. So If you have created a signature with "POST" in the signature base string, but actually send it as a GET... it wont work.

**Possible problem 2**.

If you are sending a POST request, then another possible problem is that you are not using POST as part of the signature base string. When you call `myOauth.GenerateSignature` what do you send as `httpMethod` parameter in the second case? Since the http method (GET or POST) is part of the signature base string. That needs to be set accordingly.

**Possible problem 3**.

Are you sending a new fresh nonce with every request?

Comment: Thank you for your help. However my issue was not at all in the signing request procedure, the http method and generated signature were correct. I actually had to precise in the request the http method before to send it : HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = method.ToString();

Comment: So in fact, it was problem one that I outlined above. That you did not send it as a POST request?

Comment: Damn! What's wrong with me?? Yes you pointed me in the right direction in the first place and I must be blind/stupid/tired to have not seen it, or misunderstood it... I've worked too much on this API I guess... Thanks ;)